# Error: Mac OS version: Not yet set

Tags: mac, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I have Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6 on DVD.

I tried to use the DVD to install onto an HP Pavilion DV6000.

It doesn't load, it shows one error: that "Mac OS version: Not yet set".

Kernel version
Darwin kernel version 10.2.0 tue april  2 00:35:29 EST 2009; annappirtrvh v2:xnu-1486.2.11/BUILD/obj/RELEASE_1386 
System model name:MacPro4,1

Please help me figure out how I can solve the error message.

My System Details
Intel® Centrino Duo (2.20GHz,1MB)
4GB Dual Channel DDR2 SDRAM 800MHz - 2DIMMs
Single Drive: 16X DVD-ROM Drive
150GB 
nvidia GeForce*Go 7400 graphic card.

Comment: Basically, until the HP Pavilion becomes a Mac, it won't work very reliably and even less legally.

Comment: We don't answer Hackintosh questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the retail OSX snow leopard, which will not load or boot on any pc.

Comment: That's not completely true. You can actually load retail disks using something like iBoot or Boot132, though it's legal to do so.

Comment: i think you mean 'illegal', but this is correct.

Comment: Oops, clumsy typo, of course I mean illegal :)